# Matlab - Ability to break a field of a struct into several smaller fields

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, logging, struct

Thank you for your support.

I have the following issue to resolve: i have measured some temperatures. the values are never below 2, and i have done several measurements. I have a field of a struct on matlab which contains all the measurements in one big log (see the picture attached). I would like to break this log into smaller ones, according to a condition seen in the data. In this case, the condition is "every time the temperature goes over 3, break the log and take that chunk of data and put it into a new field".

Could you please help me on the matter?

Please let me know if you need further explanation to clarify the issue.

thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you wish to break up a field of a structure when a certain value goes above three, and create a new field with the following values up until the next three.

Here's an example. Given

```
s.Temperature = [1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5];
```

the following code:

```
indx = find(diff(s.Temperature > 3) == 1);
l = length(indx);

for i=1:l
    if i==l
        s = setfield(s,['new_field_', num2str(i)],s.Temperature(indx(i):end));
    else
        s = setfield(s,['new_field_', num2str(i)],s.Temperature(indx(i):indx(i+1) - 1));
    end
end
```

will generate:

```
s = 

  struct with fields:

    Temperature: [1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5]
    new_field_1: [3 4 5 2]
    new_field_2: [3 4 5]
```

When you are done, you can simply delete the field `Temperature`:

```
rmfield(s,'Temperature')
```